# How can I see large thumbnails of the files I want to attach to an e-mail?

Tags: evolution, files, thumbnails

When I want to attach a file (an image) with Evolution, it's very hard to pick the good file because thumbnails are **way** to small.

How can I make them bigger?

Comment: If the images are too small to be useful, this sounds more like a bug.  Please could you file a report about it in the Launchpad bug-tracker so that a proper solution can be investigated and found for ***everyone,*** rather than just as a quick workaround for one person!  Thank you for getting involved in making Ubuntu better for everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Changing the size of thumbnails unfortunately is not (yet?) implemented in the Gtk File Chooser used here. Unless the application in question does not use another file chooser there will be not much change to this, I'm afraid.

From [Bugzilla bug #141154](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141154) there are some patches around now. Launchpad [bug #137606](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtk/+bug/137606) has state *in progress*.

Answer (score 3):

While this isn't directly related to the file chooser in Gnome, you can alternatively open a file browser to your Pictures folder and drag/drop into the composing email. This will allow you to zoom in with all the full functionality of the file browser. Evolution is fully drag/drop compliant.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing right now. But it's a cheap workaround, isn't it.

Answer (score 2):

It's control and scroll up on your mouse or control shift =/+

This is because evolution isn't packaged with it's own file browser (like most apps), but uses Nautilus (or whatever your default is, again, like most apps). This is done for unity in your interface and because programmers, in general, are lazy.